# Yii2 GridView multiple rows for one record

Tags: php, yii2

I am new in Yii2 framework. I did Gii table, and I wanted to show multiple data related to one ID.

Here is my Grid View:

```
 <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,

    'columns' => [
        'asosSlave.tovar_nom',


    ],
]); ?>
```

However, it is only showing one piece of information related to that id:

[image: Screenshot of data]

Comment: add controller code

Comment: public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }   This is my controller, however my actionView doesnt work as i have changed the view.php, and popup window works through index.php

Answer (score -1):

is this mean?

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,

    'columns' => [
        'asosSlave.tovar_nom',
        ['label'=>'title','value'=>function($model){
             // do you want to do and return 
        )}]
    ],
]); ?>
```